# Phpunit Testing Controller only unauthorized symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, controller, phpunit

I'm trying to test my controller and for some reason the only status code received is `UNAUTHORIZED`. I am not sure what the problem is so I hope someone can give me a hand. I'm using SYmfony 3.4 and this is my code:

The loginFormAuth:

```
protected function login(array $roles = ['ROLE_USER'])
{
    $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');

    $firewallContext = 'api';

    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken('test', null, $firewallContext, $roles);
    $session->set('_security_' . $firewallContext, serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
}

protected function requestUrl($url)
{
    return $this->client->request('GET', $url);
}


public function testGetProductsAsAdmin()
{
    $this->logIn(array('ROLE_ADMIN');

    $url = 'api/products';
    $this->getUrl($url);

    $this->assertSame(Response::HTTP_OK, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}


public function getProductAction(Request $request, ListProductService $service)
{
    $this->checkAccess($this->getUser()); // so here only the admin has permission

    $result = $service->execute();

    return new Response($this->serializer->serialize($result));
}
```

security.yml

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/products, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What role do you see when looking in the symfony toolbar?

Comment: Not sure where to look. The debug is not working, and in the console it doesn't say such thing. Only that is returned 401 instead of 200.

Answer (score 0):

one thing i notice above is, in the function : `testGetProductsAsAdmin()`, you call a function : `$this->getUrl($url);` dont see that function in the code you listed, do you want to call

```
$this->requestUrl($url);?
```

also question, `return $this->client->request('GET', $url);`are you missing the token in this request?

Comment: Yes, that function calls the $this->client->request('GET', $url);

Comment: Ok so in your test, did you call the correct method: $this->requestUrl($url), and were you able to assert on 200 response after that?